# How to overcome build time limit for Haskell projects on Heroku?

Tags: haskell, heroku, build, limit

I'm trying to deploy Haskell application to Heroku using the following buildpack:

- https://github.com/mfine/heroku-buildpack-stack

The build is going well until it hits the build time limit with the following error:

```
-----> Timed out running buildpack Haskell
 !     Push failed
```

Is there any way to increase this limit or to speed up the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split dependencies in half and make a push with only part of the dependencies enabled. Then make a push with all of them enabled. The latter build will use cached dependencies from the former build. If the project is super heavy on dependencies it would probably require more than two steps though.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked for me. It's not automatic, because I have to spend a lot of time manually first time and each time I perform a significant dependencies upgrade. But it works. And it is what it is. I will accept this answer if there will be no more convenient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with my angular project in a VPS with 1GB ram. I solved it by building the project in my local environment first and then uploading build files to the server.

Comment: This is a solid solution. However, it doesn't work if you have different systems. Like Windows locally and Linux on a deployment service. Also, I'm not sure how to upload build artefacts with heroku.